# Fixed-point method for $x=x+wf(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

The equation $f(x)=x^3+x-1=0$ admites a unique solution $\alpha\in[0;1]$. I want to approximate the solution $\alpha$ using fixed-point method, for that, sitting
 $x=g(x)=x+wf(x)$ an equivalent of $f(x)=0$. So we get for $g(0), g(1)\in[0;1]$, $w\in[-1;0]$.

**My question:** $w$ belongs to which interval in order to apply the fixed-point method.

Comment: And your take on this would be, what?

Comment: The fixed-point method cannot be applied for all $w\in[-1;0]$ see for example $w=-1$ and $w=-0.5$  do not work.

Comment: Yes. And? $ $ $ $

Comment: I think that all $w\in [-1;-0.5]$ the method does not work, so $w\in [-0.5;0]$. And the other values of $w$?

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize this iteration using phase plots for the iteration $x_{k+1}=g(x_k)$.

[image: phase portraits]

The gallery shows behavior from periodic cycles and then convergence to the fixed point, the root of $f$, with fastest convergence around $w=-0.6$. You can quantify this by considering the contraction factor $$q=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|g'(x)|=\max|1-wf'(x)|.$$ Then if $|2g(0.5)-1|=|2wf(0.5)|<1-q$ one has also $$g([0,1])\subset[g(0.5)-0.5q,\, g(0.5)+0.5q]\subset[0,1]$$ by the mean value theorem, and thus a fixed point.

Comment: Calculating $g'(x)=1+w(3x^2+1)$, this gives  $max_{x\in[0;1]}|g'(x)|=max|1+w(3x^2+1) |=|1+4w|$.

Comment: For a monotonous function crossing the zero axis you need to consider the absolute value at both interval ends, $q=\max(|1+w|, |1+4w|)$. Then combine with $g(\frac12)=\frac12-\frac38w$ to the condition $\frac34|w|+\max(|1+w|,|1+4w|)<1$. The left side is minimal for $w=-0.4$ with value $q=0.6$.